# How to fix the error on erasing element from a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, tree

I want to erase a particular element from a vector and I tried the following code. Actually I want to build a adjacency list and I want to delete an element from the adjacency list and to delete all edges connected to deleted element.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
vector<vector<int> > tree(20);
void addEdge(int u, int v)
{
    tree[u].push_back(v);
    tree[v].push_back(u);
}

void printGraph(vector<vector<int>> tree [], int V)
{
    vector<vector<int>>::iterator it;
    int j;
    for (it = tree.begin(); it != tree.end(); )
    {
        cout << "\n Adjacency list of vertex ";
        for (j = 0; j < (*it).size(); j++)
        {
            cout << j << "\n head ";
            cout << "-> " << (*it)[j];
        }
        cout << endl;
        if (j==2) it = tree.erase(it);
    }
}   
int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    addEdge(1, 2);
    addEdge(3, 2);
    addEdge(4, 2);
    addEdge(2, 5);
    printGraph(tree, n);
}
```

How to fix the error on erasing element from a vector?

Comment: `vector<int> tree[20];` declares a raw array of 20 `vector<int>`. As a raw array it doesn't have any member functions, e.g. no `begin`. There are ways around it but if  you really want an array of arrays, of dynamic size, then use a `vector` of `vector`.

Comment: how to iterate vector<int> tree[20];

Comment: The easiest way to iterate through a raw array is to use indexing, i.e. increment an integer variable `i` through all positions. Alternatively, since you directly have the array at hand, you can use `std::begin` and `std::end` from the `<iterator>` header to produce begin and end iterators.

Comment: can you correct this std::vector<int>::iterator itVec1 = tree.begin();
 for( ; itVec1 != tree.end(); )

Comment: @student if you are using C++11 or later, use `std::begin()` and `std::end()` to get iterators for a raw array. Or use `std::array` instead, which has `begin()` and `end()` methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your immediate needs, use

```
for (it = tree.begin(); it != tree.end(); ) // loops on the entire tree
{
    for (int j = 0; j < (*it).size(); j++) // loops through adjacent vertices in the current node
        cout << ' ' << (*it)[j];
    cout << endl;

    it = tree.erase(it); // erase current node (same thing as it = tree.erase(it.begin()))
}
```

to print your tree and linearly delete each row.

---

**Original Answer before question was updated:**

as a static array of `std::vector<int</code>'s, we won't be able to use `std::vector<></code> member functions directly on tree (e.g. `tree.begin()</code> generates an error because there is no `.begin()</code> member function for a static array).>

An alternative is to use `std::begin(tree)` and `std::end(tree)` defined from the `<iterator>` header file.

But since, you're wanting to delete (erase) parts of the array, a better way of structuring this data is to use `std::vector<std::vector<int>> tree(20)` which will create a 2D array. Here, the `.erase()` member function is valid.

**Alternative to Storing Data** (Helpful)

Also I believe adjacency matrices usually have static size? For example:

```
    A  B  C

A   0  1  0

B   1  0  1

C   0  1  0
```

would show that there are 3 nodes (A, B, C) and there are two edges (AB, BC).

Removing an edge would just be as simple as changing the edge from 1 to 0. Here, you can use `std::vector<int> tree[20]` or better, `bool tree[20][20]` (should use bool since we're only dealing with 1's and 0's). Then you would need to reimplement the `addEdge` function, but that should be in your scope of understanding.

Hope this helps.